# How to get the first value from the listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox where the user has generated a list of random numbers into it, and im trying to output the first value from the listbox to a label text. However, just seems to be outputting a random number instead.

```
while (lstHoldValue.Items.Count < MAX_ITEMS)
{
    int value = rnd.Next(1 + 100);//ranges from 0 - 100
    if (!lstHoldValue.Items.Contains(value))
        lstHoldValue.Items.Add(value);
}
int d = (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[0]));
label11.Text = d.ToString();
```

Comment: You're showing the first item, however the first item _is a random integer_ between 1 and 100 since you're generating a new value for every item. The correct way to use the `Next` method by the way is: `rnd.Next(1, 101)`.

Comment: *mynamea sas* doesn't know ether ? ;-)

Comment: What do you expect to be the content of the label?

Comment: When does this Lisbox get filled ? Is the list box empty before you generate all these random numbers and put them in ? The code you posted works perfectly fine.

Comment: @VisualVincent `rnd.Next(1 + 100)` is perfect syntax, it's perfectly possible/fine to only give in the parameter of `maxValue`, although you would likely see it more as `rnd.Next(101)`

Comment: @Jim : Yes you're right. I think I mixed this up with a `Random` from another language.

Comment: your code is terribly inefficient. that `while` loop may repeat thousand times just to fill list with 100 unique random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert item to string first. Your code should be like:

```
int d = (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[0].ToString()));
label11.Text = d.ToString();
```

Edited:

I think @Visual Vincent is right. I've made a mistake here :). Your code should work without that. ToString method is not necessary.

```
int d = (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[0]));
Text = d.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: What? My mind is blown right now... How can this work? It should make no difference at all...

Comment: I have to test this with his code... Something is not right.

Comment: I think you are right @VisualVincent it does not make any difference at all.

Comment: also OP needs to shuffle an array (or list) instead of trying to fill list with random numbers.

Comment: I just tested it and can now verify that it doesn't make any difference. @rustymolle : What is the result you wanted and what did you get using your code?

Comment: I cannot use any arrays in my program or containers just the listbox item properties, is there a better way to generate values ?